# Exporting Access Query to Excel Brings Over Primary Key, Not Information

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a fairly expansive Access DB with quite a few relationships between tables. In that database I have created 10 or so Queries that I need to export to excel and have the data in those cells come over not the primary key that identifies them in a related table. I have used the following code to perform the export.

```
Public Function Export_To_Excel()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "My Query", "File Path" 
End Function
```

The function works as expected but in Excel the related fields come over as numbers as opposed to text. Please see image below: [Same information in Excel vs. Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vDtJ.png)

I was wondering if anyone knew how to transfer Access data to Excel as it is without having primary key come over instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're using lookup fields in the result of your query. Excel is only seeing the underlying value in your lookup field, while access is actually looking up the appropriate values.

If you want to fix this, you will need to join your query with the table your lookup fields are getting their values from, and actually select the columns you want to see instead of the lookup fields.